# metric $(dx) ^a+(dt)^a$

Tags: metric-spaces, physics, general-relativity

Could a metric defined on a 2-dimensional space $(x,t)$ by

$(ds) ^a=(dx) ^a+(c(dt))^a $

where $a=a(x,t)>1$ and $c=$ speed of light

have any sense in physics?
$\left(\text{for example } a=2-\frac{\sin x}{1000}\right)$

Answer (score 2):

The exponent really does need to be $2$. We want to be able to raise and lower indices with metric tensors viz. $V_a=g_{ab}V^b,\,V^b=g^{bc}V_c$ so $g_{ab}g^{bc}=\frac{\partial V_a}{\partial V_c}=\delta_a^c$. Then $ds^2=g_{ab}dx^adx^b$. An alternative coordinate system with $ds^2=g_{AB}dy^Ady^B$ implies $g_{AB}=g_{ab}\frac{\partial x^a}{\partial y^A}\frac{\partial x^b}{\partial y^B}$ by the chain rule.

Comment: @AntonioFarro An expression of the form $g_{ab}dx^adx^b$ is a homogeneous degree-$2$ polynomial in the $dx^a$. It'd be weird to define $ds$ so this was anything other than $ds^2$. For starters, it ensures that in Cartesian coordinates $g_{ab}$ is dimensionless while $ds$ is a length.

Comment: The universe doesn't care to be weird

Comment: @AntonioFarro You don't know how right you are.